# Can you pickup a gun and have it default to automatic fire?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I wish to know if is there any option or possibility to take a gun from the floor and it has the automatic mode turned on always.

When you take a gun or weapon, you must push the <kbd>B</kbd> to switch between single, auto, etc., and it happens with all of them, the default value is single.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last I played, there is no option that changes the default fire mode of a weapon when you pick it up off the ground.

I believe that if you pick up a weapon from dead persons loot box or a weapon that someone dropped, it will be in whatever fire mode that they were using it in last before they died/dropped the weapon.  These are the only exception to this.  You will have to simply remember to switch the fire mode upon picking a weapon up.

**Edit:**

With the Update #25 Patch, there is now a game option to set the default weapon fire mode of guns.  Reading the [patch notes](https://www.pubg.com/2019/01/23/test-server-update-25-patch-notes/) for the update:

> Added an option to set default firing mode for weapons